# Create a function in Kotlin that requires annotation every time it is used while coding like a warning

Tags: android, function, kotlin, annotations

I have a custom annotation class

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class  MyCustomAnnotation
```

And a function

```
fun myFunction() {
//Code here
}
```

How to require MyCustomAnnotation every time myFunction() is called while coding, and if there is no annotation, a warning will be displayed a option to add annotation.

[Warning option like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNXvM.png)

My expectations

```
@MyCustomAnnotation 
myFunction()
```

Comment: You could maybe try [@RequiresOptIn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-requires-opt-in/), but why do you need this? Annotating calls to a function doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: You should write customer Lint for that, Lint is responsible for showing warning .
Read https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@OptIn` feature to give this functionality ([documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html)).

Update your annotation definition to the following, modifying the message to something appropriate:

```
@RequiresOptIn(message = "Requires opt in when calling function")
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyCustomAnnotation
```

Add the annotation to the definition of your function:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
fun myFunction() {
   //Code here
}
```

Then, when calling the function, opt in as follows to prevent a warning:

```
@OptIn(MyCustomAnnotation::class)
myFunction()
```

Comment: Great :) upvotes/accepting answers always appreciated